# Imac 20 inch 2009 OSX 10.9.5

Tags: macos, mac, applications, mac-appstore

I have an issue with Mac App store not opening - probably due to using Clean My Mac which has now been trashed!

Is there any way I can download a new OS without using App Store - the iMac does;t have a restore disk or partition!

Cheeers

Ian

Comment: Is there an error when you try to open the store? Or does the store simply not open?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following commands to fix that.

1. Open the Terminal application (located in /Applications/Utilities)
2. Type in the following commands:

   `sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist`

   `sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.storeagent.plist`
3. Type in your password when prompted, (your password won't appear when you type it, this is perfectly normal).

Now the Mac App Store should work again.

Comment: What if terminal won't even open? Mine does the same thing. All the apps come up on the tray and disappear immediately.